# How can I catch a specific exception

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, exception

How can I catch a specific exception? For example, in Java EE project `SQLException` may occur. For catching purpose we write

```
catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it can happen due to different reasons like

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.PK_USERID) violated

or

> Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>   ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
>   The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
>   localhost:1521:XE .

So if I want to catch specifically which exception is happening how can I implement it in the code? A code snippet will be very much helpful!!

Comment: So I modified my code and tried `catch (SQLException sqle) {String sqlMessage = sqle.getMessage(); String sqlState = sqle.getSQLState(); int vendorCode = sqle.getErrorCode(); System.err.println("Exception occurred:"); System.err.println("Message: " + sqlMessage); System.err.println("SQL state: " + sqlState); System.err.println("Vendor code: " + vendorCode); }` according to [this‌]​(http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.sql/SQLExceptiongetErrorCode.htm). But it is not printing any of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you want to respond to exceptions differently depending on what the result of `e.getMessage()` is.  For that purpose, I would advise a series of if statements within the catch block; you almost certainly want to catch the exception whatever it is (since uncaught exceptions are trouble), so you don't need to decide whether or not to catch based on anything other than the fact that it is an exception.

EDIT: if it is your own method throwing certain exceptions, you could subclass SQLException to signify different variations on the original class, and catch those individually.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about `java.sql.SQLException`, please check its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) as there are a ton of subclasses of that exception that you can individually catch (and subclasses of **those** subclasses, as well). Plus, if you are using any frameworks, there's a chance they provide even more `SQLException` subclasses of their own. You can check this easily within your IDE. In Eclipse it is called the *Type Hierarchy* view.

Answer (score 1):

catch, check if that is the message, if not then rethrow.

Answer (score 0):

What you have given are various messages of the `SQLException.`
If you have to handle them differently you may have to use either if statements
or switch statements for `e.getMessage()`